# Tunnel (Android) system wide network traffic through proxy using the VpnService API

Tags: android, proxy

I looking for a way to tunnel all network traffic through a proxy.

Since it is not possible to control a system-wide proxy without root access, Android's [VpnService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) seems like the only possibility to achieve this.

I know I need to extend the VpnService class and create a [Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html), as well as to call the .establish() method to create a new VPN interface.

Now, what parameter of the Builder class do I have to use to establish a connection to a proxy and direct all traffic it?